# Ubuntu Notification Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.Notifications: No such file or directory (23)

Tags: linux, python, d-bus, notifications, freedesktop

i was working on a python script that displays notification, here's the library I'm using https://www.devdungeon.com/content/desktop-notifications-linux-python

```
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init("App Name")
Notify.Notification.new("Hi").show()
```

it works fine when I run it without sudo but when I run it with sudo, it gives error

```
GLib.Error: g-dbus-error-quark: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.Notifications: No such file or directory (23)
```

I'm using ubuntu 18 with gnome, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, added a file in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service`
with

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

in it

Comment: Worth mentioning to install notification-daemon, e.g. `sudo apt-get install notification-daemon` in order to get the notification daemon folder. Adding the above text in the file mentioned in the answer did it for me too.